# Codename one - supports authentication if the webapi developed using IdentityServer(Open ID implementation)

Tags: codenameone

Codename one as the UI, will this support authentication of Webapi which is developed on IdentityServer (Open ID implementation)

[SSL Handshake Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seHRO.jpg)

Comment: Codename One supports OAuth2 which can be used as the starting point for an open id implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/f96a2d46aa2f51b9e382d63ef1ef359963a7f0d2/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/Oauth2.java

Comment: Thanks Shai. When tried to connect to Identity server it is throwing Connection Reset error. java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Is this related to Codename one library or something on the server causing this issue.Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell, you need to go thru the protocol differences between OAuth2 and the identity server. You can also use the network monitor tool to see what is sent between the client and the server (notice that it won't show the communication done by the web browser)

Comment: Hi Shai,I see the same error in the networking tool as well. Connection reset error. I'm not sure this is something to do with the settings at server level.Please find the sever SSL hand shake information related to java. Please see the attached screeenshot. Server blocks 8u31 version of java, but i'm using latest version of java. Please guide me.

Comment: That looks related to Java SSL support so it's failing before it even reaches our code. If this something you got working in Java SE?

Comment: No Shai. I have tried with Java SE it returns same error. So it might be somethign with the server settings.

Comment: On server, for testing purpose I'm using the Http request and able to make the call. But it was giving 411: Length Required for a Post request. Do we need to send the content-length parameter while sending the post request? If yes, Can you guide me an example. Thanks

Comment: MultipartRequest sends content length https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.java

Answer (score 1):

Your Client, Codename one, has to register on Identity Server as valid client. And the requests originating from the client will have to authenticate with Identity provider (identity server) and receive an access token with which they can access the API.

Open ID implementation is a standard and is not tied to any technology like .net or java. Please provide more details if you have more questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: Thank You Soma. But when tried to connect to IDentity server it is throwing Connection Reset error. java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Is this related to Codename one library or something on the server causing this issue.Thanks